# Query String for the WP_QUERY parameters

Tags: query, query-string

I don't know how to turn some WP QUERY parameters into url query strings. Most of them are straight forward, but there are some I don't know how to get working. For example, for these WP_QUERY parameters:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    's' => 'keyword',
);
```

the query string for this is: `?s=keyword&post_type=post`

What is the query string for the 'after' parameter with value '24 hours ago'. For example, this WP_QUERY gets posts created in the last 24 hours:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'  => '24 hours ago',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But I don't know the query string for it. This doesn't work:

```
?after=24%20hours%20ago
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `&date=24%20hours%20ago`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP function [http_build_query();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) would return different string for this array. It won't remain readable like an array but, I believe, it will work as parameter to WP_Query.

[build_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/build_query) is the WordPress equivalent for the same functionality.

Turns out that `build_query` is a bit different from `http_build_query`.

`http_build_query` returned `date_query%5B0%5D%5Bafter%5D=24+hours+ago` and `build_query` returned `date_query%5B0%5D%5Bafter%5D=24 hours ago`. I guess, later would work for WP_Query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried them but they don't work either. All the other date parameters inside the 'date_query' work just by adding year=value&month=value&w=value&day=value&hour=value. As stated here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters. I thought just by using after=value and before=value would work too but they don't.

Answer (score 0):

The codex says you can use any strtotime() compatible string so you could use:

> 'after'  => '-24 hours'

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need it to be a URL query string, not as an array. in the form of ?key=value&key=value. If you visite https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters and scroll down to where it says 'Returns posts for today' it shows how to write it. year=value&monthnum=value&day=value all work. But after=value doesn't work.